# How to SELECT ALL FROM SQLite table and then save true or false answer into a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, select, cordova

I am trying to select everything from contracts db and compare the first name of HTML5 textbox with the db entry to alert for duplicates. My first target is to save the result of the query into sql2 variable. ( I cannot do that , please help! ).

```
db = window.openDatabase("contactDB", "1.0", "Contact Database", 1000000); //name,version,display name, size
addButton.addEventListener(
  "click",
  function(){
    db.transaction(
    //function sql statements
    function (tx){
       ensureTableExists(tx);
       var firstName = firstNameBox.value;
       var lastName = lastNameBox.value;

       var sql = 'INSERT INTO Contacts (firstName, lastName) VALUES ("'+firstName+'","'+lastName+'")';
       tx.executeSql(sql);

           // Attempting to check for duplicates
       var sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM Contacts', WHERE firstName = "'+firstname+'";                                                                 
       tx.executeSql(sql2);
       alert(sql2);
    }, 
    //error callback
    function (err) { alert("error callback "+err.code); },
    //success callback
    function (err) { //alert("success callback "+err.code);
      loadFromDB();
    }) // db.trasaction
  } // click handler
);
```

Comment: Obligatory comment about sql injection

Comment: sql does not have variables, it has tables.

Comment: Please check my edits -- you did not have your `)` and `}` correct.

Answer (score 0):

Lookin at this line:

```
var sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM Contacts', WHERE firstName = "'+firstname+'";
```

JS variable "firstname" is mistyped (No capital N on Name). This will turn your query into:

```
'SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE firstName = "undefined"'
```

Also, why is there `',` before `WHERE`? I am surprised you did not get an error.

Try rewriting your query like so:

```
var sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE firstName = "'+firstName+'"';
```